# Is it possible to add multiple paths in an Xcode Run Script for Parse Crash Reporting?

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, run-script

I currently have the Run Script for `ParseCrashReporting` as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd cd /Users/Computer1/projects/someProject/parse 

parse symbols "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

The  problem is the code is source controlled and when I pull at another computer the path is no longer valid is there a way to have two paths in the script?

something like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd /Users/Computer1/projects/someProject/parse OR cd /Users/Computer2/projects/someProject/parse

parse symbols "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you replace `/Users/Computer1` with `~`? E.g.: `~/projects/someProject/parse `. `~` is the unix way of saying "the current users home directory".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use $PROJECT_DIR

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
cd $PROJECT_DIR/parse

parse symbols "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"/parse

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had to figure this one out for your exact reasons.

I used the code:

`cd $PROJECT_DIR"/parse`

That is more universal and allows me to utilize git for working on different computers.